# How to handle Siri kit with INPlayMediaIntent to play Podcast episode in Xamarin.iOS app?

Tags: c#, xamarin, xamarin.ios, siri, sirikit

I have followed all steps mentioned here for Siri:
https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/xamarin/ios/platform/sirikit/implementing-sirikit?tabs=macos

Also followed: https://developer.apple.com/documentation/sirikit/media/managing_audio_with_sirikit

**IntentHandler.cs:**

```
[Register("IntentHandler")]
public class IntentHandler : INExtension, IINPlayMediaIntentHandling, IINAddMediaIntentHandling
{
    protected IntentHandler(IntPtr handle) : base(handle)
    { 
    }

    public override NSObject GetHandler(INIntent intent)
    {
        return this;
    }

    //INPlayMediaIntent

    public void resolveMediaItems(INPlayMediaIntent intent, Action<INPlayMediaMediaItemResolutionResult> completion)
    {
        var mediaItemData = new INMediaItem(identifier: SessionService.LastPlayedEpisode.PodcastId, title: SessionService.LastPlayedEpisode.Title, type: INMediaItemType.PodcastEpisode, artwork: null);
        MessagingCenter.Send<object, string>(this, "PlayRecentEpisodeSiriEvent", "ResolveMediaItems");
        completion(INPlayMediaMediaItemResolutionResult.GetSuccess(mediaItemData));
    }

    public void HandlePlayMedia(INPlayMediaIntent intent, Action<INPlayMediaIntentResponse> completion)
    {
        var userActivity = new NSUserActivity("INPlayMediaIntent");
        var response = new INPlayMediaIntentResponse(INPlayMediaIntentResponseCode.HandleInApp, userActivity);
        completion(response);
    }

    public void HandleAddMedia(INAddMediaIntent intent, Action<INAddMediaIntentResponse> completion)
    {
        var userActivity = new NSUserActivity("INAddMediaIntent");
        var response = new INAddMediaIntentResponse(INAddMediaIntentResponseCode.Success, userActivity);
        completion(response);
    }
}
```

Now, when I give command to Siri to like: "Play The Daily in myappname" it show this:

So, I am not getting actually how siri will handle Media content to show my app with command. Anyone know:

1. How to handle Siri Media Intent in Xamarin.iOS ?
2. How to add Siri Support with Xamarin.iOS?

> UPDATE: 29 Oct, 2020 - How to play particular episode of Podcast from
> Playlist is siri?

I am trying to play particular episode of Podcast playlist but it's not working. I have given command to siri like: `Play the Overlap by audiochuck from CounterClock podcast in siridemo`

`here siridemo = my app's name, Overlap = episode name, counterclock = Podcast name.`

I am getting only CounterClock in mediasearch.medianame object when control comes to HandleIntent method in appdelegate. So it is possible to achieve this with Siri?

**How to fix app hasn't added support for that with siri error?**

[image]

Comment: What's your ios version ?

Comment: 14.0 @LeoZhu-MSFT

Comment: Is it because the phrase you want to invoke doesn't work?Try changing phrases or adding custom statements.

Comment: I have tried with different phrases and also I have done code according to demo I have got from apple documentation. Actual issue is IntentExtension don't get called I think that's why it's not working. Do you know how IntentExtension get called?

Comment: Did you configure the Intents Extension in `Info.plist` file ?

Comment: I have configure that in Intents project info.plist file i.e. NSExtension. I have to extension in main iOS project's Info.plist file?

Comment: @LeoZhu-MSFT here is my demo if you want to check - shorturl.at/iwPRW

Comment: I couldn't open your link, and I may not be able to test your demo as it involves third-party applications.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

## I have got the solution and it's here.

---

### **1. Intent Handler in your IntentExtension project:**

`First mistake I have done was I have used INPlayMediaIntentResponseCode.Success instead of HandleInApp, which I have corrected here. Why HandleInApp? Hold on :)`

```cs
[Register("IntentHandler")]
public class IntentHandler : INExtension, IINPlayMediaIntentHandling
{
   protected IntentHandler(IntPtr handle) : base(handle) { }

   public override NSObject GetHandler(INIntent intent)
   {
      return this;
   }

   [Export("handlePlayMedia:completion:")]
   public void HandlePlayMedia(INPlayMediaIntent intent, Action<INPlayMediaIntentResponse> completion)
   {
      var response = new INPlayMediaIntentResponse(INPlayMediaIntentResponseCode.HandleInApp, null);
      completion(response);
   }
}
```

---

### **2. Now let's Handle it in AppDelegate:**

`As we have passed HandleInApp as a response in Intent handler's HandlePlayMedia() it will call HandleIntent() method in AppDelegate of your main iOS project. Where the magic will happen.`

```cs
public async override void HandleIntent(UIApplication application, INIntent intent, Action<INIntentResponse> completionHandler)
{
   var playMediaIntent = intent as INPlayMediaIntent;
   
   // The command you will give to siri will come here in MediaSearch object 
   var mediaName = playMediaIntent?.MediaSearch?.MediaName;

   // Check if the Searched Podcast and episode is there in your Podcasts list or 
   // not and handle it accordingly
   var response = new INPlayMediaIntentResponse(INPlayMediaIntentResponseCode.Failure, userActivity);;
   
   if(mediaName.Exist(Playlist))
   {
       response = new INPlayMediaIntentResponse(INPlayMediaIntentResponseCode.ContinueInApp, null);
   }
   else
   {
       response = new INPlayMediaIntentResponse(INPlayMediaIntentResponseCode.FailureUnknownMediaType, null);
   }
   completionHandler(response);
}
```

---

```js
Give search command to siri like this - 

Play [EpisodeName] of [PodcastName] in your app name

For Example: `Play Conclusion in Selling Girls of America in siridemo app`
```

---

## Output:

`Now in MediaSearch.MediaName you will get "Conclusion in Selling Girls of America" as search string.`

Happy Coding!